# List cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java

folks.. I've already looked up the similar issues and did not find anything similar to mine. I'm getting "List cannot be resolved to a type" after throwing an exception in the line

```
else
    throw new ExceptionLogicMalformedSignal(c, "Invalid character!");
```

inside the `fromString(char c)` method. What have I done wrong in the code? Why is it happening to a non-list method? Thanks in advance!

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;


public enum Signal {

    HI, LO, X;


    public Signal invert()
    {
        if(this == HI)
            return LO;
        else if(this == LO)
            return HI;
        else if(this == X)
            return X;

        return this;
    }

    public static Signal fromString(char c)
    {

        if(c == '1')
            return HI;
        else if(c == '0')
            return LO;
        else if(c == 'X')
            return X;
        else if(c == 'x')
            return X;
        else
            throw new ExceptionLogicMalformedSignal(c, "Invalid character!");

    }

    public List <Signal> fromString(String inps)
    {
        List<Signal> values = new LinkedList<Signal>();
        if(inps.equals("1"))
           values.add(HI);
        else if(inps.equals("0"))
            values.add(LO);
        else if(inps.equals("X"))
            values.add(X);
        else if(inps.equals("x"))
            values.add(X);
        else 
            throw new ExceptionLogicMalformedSignal(inps.charAt(0), "Invalid character!");

        return values;

    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        if(this == HI)
            return "1";
        else if(this == LO)
            return "0";
        else if(this == X)
            return "X";

        return "Error here!";
        }
    }



public class ExceptionLogicMalformedSignal extends RuntimeException {

    private char bad; //offending character 
    private String msg = "You entered an invalid character"; //the entire message you want to convey

    public ExceptionLogicMalformedSignal(char bad, String msg)
    {
        this.bad = bad;
        this.msg = msg;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return msg;
    }

    public String getBad()
    {
        String value = Character.toString(this.bad);
        return value;
    }

    public String msg()
    {
        return msg;
    }

    public void setBad(String bad)
    {
        String value = Character.toString(this.bad);
        value = bad;
    }

    public void setMsg(String msg)
    {
        this.msg = msg;
    }

}
```

Comment: Where's the stacktrace? Did you clean and recompile? This smells of stale code.

Comment: Are you using Eclipse?

Comment: That's too awesome, @pbabcdefp. The imports are there.

Comment: Yes, I'm using eclipse @pbabcdefp

Comment: How are you calling fromString()? One is static, the other is not. Are you trying to assign a Signal return value to a List<Signal> object?

Comment: @mttdbrd, public static List<Signal> fromString(String inps) is supposed to  create and return the List of Signal values found in the input string.

Comment: I understand what it does, but how are you calling it? One method is static and the other is not. By the way, I'm able to run this code without any exceptions.

Comment: @mttdbrd, I have not called it yet, I just woud like to run some prepared by instructors test cases; I do have to include throwing exception in those methods. But what does it have to do with calling fromString()? Im pretty sure it would give me an error once I already have this error in the method.

Comment: Are you using eclipse build automatically? If not, try to rebuild the project. You should be receiving an outdated error.

Comment: Also, this is a horrible antipattern: Java enums are classes. Instead of using switches all over the place, give the enum a constructor and assign values to instance fields.

Comment: If you're getting this error after you throw the exception, then there is nothing wrong with the method.  However, the code that is handling the exception may be causing your issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
List cannot be resolved to a type
```

is a *compiler error.* You don't get it 'after throwing a exception'. You get it when compiling a line of code that uses `List.`

You need

```
import java.util.List;
```

Despite what you posted, clearly it isn't there.